# Separate a buildings' polygons shapefile layer into single layers of the single exctracted building in QGIS

Tags: qgis, vector, extract, rooftop-building

I'm new here in QGIS.

I have a shapefile layer composed of polygons, that represents the rooftop buildings of my case of study. I'd like to "exctract" every single building from my shapefile layer in order to create a standalone vector of every single building.
Is there a simple way to do it?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the "**Split vector layer**" processing algorithm https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeneral.html#qgissplitvectorlayer

Comment: Thank you. It did work!